# Deploying WCF Service on Non SharePoint Envirnment

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010

I have a plain .Net based WCF Service which is interacting with SharePoint (2010) Site. I need to deploy it on the Production environment which is not a SharePoint environment. After creating and deploying the solution its giving error

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified "
Please help me with the steps to create a deployment package for NON-SharePoint Environment.

Thanks
Yamini

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your WCF on non-Sharepoint environment, You cannot use Sharepoint server object model inside wcf. 
You need to use Client object model and add reference to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client and Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime